# Hibernate does not work with systemd in 17.10

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, 17.10, hibernate, systemd

I have enabled hibernate in freshly installed Kubuntu 17.10 by editing the file:

```
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

The machine is Lenovo V310 with secureboot disabled.

When I run `s2disk` the system hibernates and resumes properly. I am using TuxOnIce. However, when I run `sudo systemctl hibernate` (which I suppose is what the GUI buttons in menu do and what I want to work in the end) the system seems to suspend and wake immediately after that.

Following an advice from Internet, I have put the following into `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hibernate
Documentation=man:systemd-suspend.service(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=sleep.target
After=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=
ExecStartPre=-/bin/run-parts -v -a pre /lib/systemd/system-sleep
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk
ExecStartPost=-/bin/run-parts -v --reverse -a post /lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

So it seems like systemd is not actually running `s2disk` or not running it properly. Or perhaps there are some additional permissions required for non-root users? What could help?

Comment: Replace the `~` in your `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStartPost` commands with the absolute path. `systemd` is not `bash`, and does not expand `~`